# I created a Dashboard using dart. It's not compiling

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I tried to create a dashboard. But it's not working. The error is saying "MyItems isn't defined for the class _DashboardState". I'm new to the dart. Please help. I tried many things but didn't work. I'm trying to learn dart. I found this tutorial in youtube video. Creator got the same error but it works fine for him. but my emulator is not running this code.

This is my dashboard.dart file code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();

}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
        title: Text('Menu',
          style: TextStyle(
            color:Colors.white,
        ),
        ),

      ),
      body: StaggeredGridView.count(

          crossAxisCount:2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical:  8.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          MyItems(Icons.healing, "Health", 0xffed622b),
          MyItems(Icons.fastfood,"Food", 0xffed622b),
          MyItems(Icons.work, "Work", 0xffed622b),
          MyItems(Icons.fitness_center, "Workout", 0xffed622b),

        ],
        staggeredTiles: [
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 130),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 130),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 130),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 130),
        ]

      ),


    );
  }
```

This is my Main.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dashboard.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Adult Care',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: Dashboard(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you created the `MyItems` class anywhere?

Comment: @Advide_Dog no, I haven't

Comment: That sounds like your issue. Check to see where they defined `MyItems` in the tutorial.

Comment: @Advice-Dog he didn't define it. Any idea where to define it?

Comment: Could you share a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @MarianoUvalle here: [link}(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEVOiv_j35w&t=1s)

Comment: If you watch part 2 they define the function MyItems, that will solve your issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABbBYebnwDQ